# How to disable a Perl/Tk window close ('X') button on Windows

Tags: button, perltk

Is there a way to make a Perl/Tk window's close ('X') button disabled?
I know how to ignore clicking it using the technique described [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/perl-win32-users@lyris.activestate.com/msg01402.html), but I would much rather have it disabled.

I'm using Perl/Tk on Windows.

Thanks,
splintor

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a Unix environment you are out of luck. The "close" button is managed by the `Window Manager` of the desktop which is a completely different process that you have no control on.

Even if by a hack you disable the "close" button the user can always bring it back 
if the window manager permits this. The enlightenment window manager for example can
enable/disable all window buttons on demand.

The technique you give in the link is doing exactly this. It does not remove
the "close" button. It just gives a **hint** to the window manager (`WM_DELETE_WINDOW`).
*It is up to the window manager if this hint will be honoured or not.*

See also the [icccm](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/) and [NetWM](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) pages.

What you want *might* be possible on Windows, but my experience with this OS
is limited so perhaps another poster will know this.

Comment: I think that since perl/TK are cross-platform (lowest common denominator) even in Windows you would need a serious hack to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have an app that I wrote, i was wondering about the same thing, and i don't disableit, but i have a call back to a subroutine, that simply does `return;`

```
$Mw->protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',sub{return;});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=855752), it looks like the following works on Windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tk;

my $window = new MainWindow;
$window ->title("Close test");
$window ->geometry("400x250");

#prevents window from closing
$window->protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW' => sub {
                       print "Do stuff before exiting\n";
                       exit;
                   });

MainLoop;
```

In the above code, you are intercepting the signal sent when the user presses 'X' and can then write your own subroutine to execute when the button is pressed.

If you want to **disable the close icon**, set `sub` to empty (effectively telling it to "do nothing when pressed"): `'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' => sub {}`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't manage to *really* disable the close button (I mean to grey it out or even remove it from the window decoration), it might be the most intuitive thing to iconify your window instead of closing it. This is what I did.

`$window->protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', sub { $window->iconify(); } );`